# Prototype lost on slice on array-like construct

Tags: javascript

I have created an array like prototype:

```
function METracker() {}
METracker.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
METracker.prototype.myMethod = function(aStd) {
    return true;
};
```

now i create an instance:

```
var aInst = new METracker('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Now I want to clone it so I do:

```
var cloneInst = aInst.slice();
```

however `cloneInst` no longer has the method `.myMethod` is there a way to keep the prototype on the clone?

Thanks

Comment: It is because `slice` returns an `Array` object, not `METracker` object and `Array` object doesn't have `myMethod`.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get slice to return `METracker` is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope, unless you can change the `slice` function itself. Otherwise, you need to build your own `slice` wrapper on `METracker`, which would slice and return a `METracker` instance.

Comment: Ah drats, makes sense. Could you please show how to build a `slice` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye I create and use it as a regular array. I always create a new one by doing `var a = new METracker()`

Comment: Note that you can't "subclass" Array this way since instances must have the special, self–adjusting *length* property, and only Array instances have that. You can't emulate it.

Comment: Thanks @RobG that's interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to create your own array-alike, the trick is to extend an array *instance*, not the array prototype:

```js
function MyAry() {
    var self = [];

    [].push.apply(self, arguments);

    // some dark magic

    var wrap = 'concat,fill,filter,map,slice';
    wrap.split(',').forEach(function(m) {
        var p = self[m];
        self[m] = function() {
            return MyAry.apply(null, p.apply(self, arguments));
        }
    });

    // add your stuff here

    self.myMethod = function() {
        document.write('values=' + this.join() + '<br>');
    };

    return self;
}


a = new MyAry(11,44,33,22);
a.push(55);
a[10] = 99;
a.myMethod()

b = a.sort().slice(0, 4).reverse();
b.myMethod();
```

Basically, you create a new array (a normal array, not your object), wrap some Array methods so that they return your object instead of generic arrays, and add your custom methods to that instance. All other array methods and the index operation keep working on your object, because it's just an array.

Comment: Thanks georg very much this works absolutely superb!

Answer (score 1):

> I have created an array like prototype:

No, you haven't.

> function METracker() {}
>      METracker.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
>      METracker.prototype.myMethod = function(aStd) {
>          return true;
>      };

The *METracker* constructor does nothing at all, it will just return a new Object with Array.prototype on its `[[Prototype]]` chain.

> var aInst = new METracker('a', 'b', 'c');

Just returns an instance of METracker, it has no data since the constructor doesn't do anything with the arguments passed. Assigning Array.prototype to the inheritance chain doesn't mean the Array constructor is invoked.

> var cloneInst = aInst.slice();

Note that callling *slice()* on *aInst* just returns a new, empty array. *aInst* doesn't have a length property, so the algorithm for *slice* has nothing to iterate over. And even if *aInst* had properties, *slice* will only iterate over the numeric ones that exist with integer values from 0 to `aInst.length - 1`.

If you want to create a constructor that creates Array–like objects, consider something like:

```js
function ArrayLike() {
  // Emulate Array constructor
  this.length = arguments.length;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function(arg, i) {
    this[i] = arg;
  }, this);
}

ArrayLike.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype); 

var a = new ArrayLike(1,2,3);
document.write(a.length);
document.write('<br>' + a.join());
```

The above is just play code, there is a lot more to do. Fixing the *length* issue isn't easy, I'm not sure it can be done. Maybe there needs to be a private "fixLength" method, but methods like *splice* need to adjust the length and fix indexes as they go, so you'll have to write a constructor that emulates the Array constructor and many methods to do re–indexing and adjust length appropriately (push, pop, shift, unshift, etc.).